# Facing issue in installation of path SUPEE 7405

Tags: magento-1.9, php, security, patches

I have upload file in root directory of SUPEE-7405 patch file. Apply below mentioned code in this file https://www.samuraimarket.net/applypatch.php:

```
    <?php
    print("<PRE>");
    passthru("/bin/bash PATCH_SUPEE-7405_CE_1.9.2.1_v1.1-2016-02-23-07-42-31.sh");
    print("</PRE>");
    echo "Done";
?>
```

Folders and Files permission are 775 and 666, So I have changed as 755 and 644 respectively.Please guide as facing issue in installation as ERROR: Patch can't be applied/reverted successfully.Magento Version is 1.9.2.1

Answer (score 0):

I have applied PATCH_SUPEE-7405_CE_1.9.2.2_v1-2016-01-20-04-35-33 instead of PATCH_SUPEE-7405_CE_1.9.2.1_v1.1-2016-02-23-07-42-31.sh. Its solved Now.

Answer (score 0):

v1.1 is an additional patch for the patch, not an updated version. So you'll need to apply **both in order**:

1. PATCH_SUPEE-7405_CE_1.9.2.2_v1-2016-01-20-04-35-33
2. PATCH_SUPEE-7405_CE_1.9.2.1_v1.1-2016-02-23-07-42-31.sh